# Add on load event for img elements now and in future?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, events

I want to add a load event on an image that would affect that image even when that image is added to the document after the page's initial load. For a click event I would do someting like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.elem', function(e) {
    // do stuff
});
```

When I try something similar with the `load` event, however, it does not to work. This is what I have tried:

```
$(document).on('load', '.image', function() {
   // do stuff
});
```

This event is simply never triggered. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong, or how to achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Please un-accept [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423669/157247) so I can delete it. This is indeed possible, and was possible even back in 2014 (sorry about that). See [Dhia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40332901/157247).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is incorrect.** It's possible to do this using the capture phase, see [Dhia Louhichi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40332901/157247). I'll delete this answer when I can (i.e.., once it's no longer the accepted answer).

---

By their nature, delegated handlers only work for events that bubble. Not all do, and `load` is one of the ones that doesn't. [The jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) even highlights this:

> In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an  element) do not bubble.

You'll have to add the load handlers to the images when you add them.

---

What I mean by "delegated handlers only work for events that bubble":

Events that bubble work like this (in the "bubbling" phase, which is the phase you normally work with): The event is fired on the element where it originates, and then on that element's parent, then *that* element's parent, etc. until it gets to the document element (`html`). This diagram from [the DOM3 events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#h3_event-flow) may help make this clearer:

[image: Graphical representation of an event dispatched in a DOM tree using the DOM event flow]

Using a delegated handler (the kind you're using in your question) relies on bubbling. Consider this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">xxxx</div>
    <div class="content">xxxx</div>
    <div class="content">xxxx</div>
</div>
```

If you do `$("#container").on("click", ".content", ...)` you're **not** hooking the event on the "content" divs, even though jQuery will make it seem a bit like you are. You're hooking the event on the "container" div. When the event bubbles down to the container div, jQuery looks at where it started and sees whether it passed through any "content" divs during its bubbling. If it did, jQuery calls your handler as though (mostly) you'd hooked the event on the "content" div. That's why delegated handlers work when you add elements later; the event isn't hooked on the element, but on the container.

So that's why it won't work for `load`: `load` doesn't bubble, so even though it fires on the `img` elements you add, it doesn't bubble to the parent and so on, and so you never see it. To see it, you have to hook it on the specific element, not an ancestor of it.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that message and wasn't sure what it mean. A "delegated handler" in this case means one that assigns an event to all future elements? I wonder if it is possible to explain why whether or not an event bubbles makes a difference in the assignment in this case....

Comment: @fraxture: It's central to how delegated handlers work. I've added an explanation, but it's worth a thorough read of the jQuery docs as well.

Comment: Wow, what a nice and interesting post, sincerely!

Comment: This answer is incorrect in that there *is* a way to do what the OP asked. See Dhia's answer. I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This code shows handling the `load` event for `img` elements created in the future, without explicitly adding a listener/handler to them, by using the capture phase of the event process on `document.body` (also works when attached to `document`, but not `window` because of backward compatibility issues):

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function (event) {
        var elm = event.target;
        if (elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
            console.log("Loaded: " + event.target.src);
        }
    },
    true // Capture phase
);
```

Live Example:

```js
document.body.addEventListener(
    "load",
    function (event) {
        var elm = event.target;
        if (elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
            console.log("Loaded: " + event.target.src);
        }
    },
    true // Capture phase
);

// Brief wait, then add an image
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        "<img src='https://via.placeholder.com/150/202080?text=Some+Image'>"
    );
}, 400);
```

This is tested and works in at least the following:

- IE9+
- Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers (Opera, Edge, Vivaldi, ...)
- Firefox
- iOS Safari

The behavior is also [documented](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-types-list). In fact, coincidentally the specification gives this example mentioning `load` by name (scroll down slightly from that link):

> EXAMPLE 5
>
> The following is one way to interpret the above tables: the `load` event will trigger event listeners attached on `Element` nodes for that event and on the capture and target phases. This event is not cancelable. If an event listener for the `load` event is attached to a node other than Window, Document, or Element nodes, or if it is attached to the bubbling phase only, this event listener would not be triggered.

That's saying `load` will be fired in the capture and target phases, but not the bubbling phase (since the event doesn't bubble).

By default, when you use `addEventListener`, the handler is attached for the target phase of the element you call `addEventListener` on and the bubbling phase for any element within that element. If you add the third argument with the value `true`, though, it attaches the handler for the target phase of the element you call `addEventListener` on (as before) and the **capture** phase for any element within that element. So the code above will handle `load` for `document.body` during the target phase (except `document.body` doesn't fire `load`) and also handle `load` for the capture phase of any element within `document.body`.

More about event flows [in the specification](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-flow), including this handy diagram:

[image: Event flow diagram showing an event starting with a "capture" phase at window, passing through document, document.body, and so on until it reaches the td it targets; doing the target phase at the td, then working back up through its ancestor elements during the "bubbling" phase until it reaches window again.]

Comment: While this may be working code, please add some explanation as why this is an answer to the question. At the same time you could maybe fix the indenting of your code.

Comment: Why not just use `$('img').load(function() {})`?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie, because it 1. does not work on elements added in the future. 2. uses jQuery 3. is now deprecated.